# how to set width and height in jspdf?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf

How to set html content responsive while setting width and height in jspdf?

below is my code but it does not gives A4 format. If I'm using A4 format then my content is not wrapping up, instead its getting cut.

```
const Click_Download = async () => {
    (window as any).html2canvas = html22canvas;
    const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [1400, 1000]);
    (doc as any).html(document.querySelector("#myid"), {
                
    callback: function(pdf: any) {
      pdf.save(mypdf.pdf");
    }
  });           
}
```

Comment: _"How to set html content responsive"_ <-- What do you mean by this? And PDF is not HTML...

Comment: If I remember correct, A4 is 595 × 842 points.

Comment: @GuidoFaecke are you talking about landscape ?

Comment: @Dai, I have html content, that is coming from server, and i want to download that as pdf.

Comment: Converting HTML to PDF (with CSS styles applied, etc) is non-trivial. The jsPDF library is a low-level PDF library for building PDFs from primitive PostScript-style drawing instructions: you can't just pass HTML into it and expect it to work (as for `html2canvas`, it breaks on CORS, it only supports a small subset of CSS properties and layout features: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features/ - its lack of fidelity is why I don't use it in my projects. For page-screenshots I use `getDisplayMedia` now and for HTML-to-PDF I use a service like Browserless.io or run a custom build of Chromium.